# Slick Slider Items change speed are not same if item width is different

Tags: javascript, jquery, slick.js, news-ticker

I want to make a news ticker with slick slider, where all of the news will scroll smoothly at a constant speed continiously. So, I used the following option:

`$('.slick-news-ticker').slick({ 
  dots: true,
  infinite: true,
  speed: 2000,
  respondTo: 'container',
  cssEase: 'linear',
  autoplay: true,
  autoplaySpeed: 0,
  variableWidth: true,
});`

But I found if item length is not same then items speed are not same for all of the items,  See the demo from codepen:
https://codepen.io/mobashir/pen/LYPQYzY

You will see that speed is different if items width are not same.

Is there any way so that I can use same speed for all of the items and items speed will not depend on the length of the items?

Please, help me, I've tried by many ways but can't find any solution.